# html - Hidden content in div tag

Tags: php, html

I would like to download content of certain page and get one number from it (still not sure how, probably using PHP DOM interface). I opened the page, started Firefox's debugging, picked the element with number and found out that is in `<div id="lblOptimizePercent" class="wod-dpsval">98.4%</div>` (98.4% is what I am looking for). So I opened its source code, Ctrl - F for `lblOptimizePercent` and all I found is this `<div id="lblOptimizePercent" class="wod-dpsval"></div>` without any content. What I've done wrong? Or is it some site's protection not to *steal* contents?

[Link to the original site](http://www.askmrrobot.com/wow/optimize/eu/drak%27thul/Ecclesiastic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, to scrape the page from PHP, you would have to

1. save the page
2. extract the value you want from HTML via a regular expression

   - alternatives include using SimpleXML for DOM querying...

The piece of HTML we are look at is:

`<div id="lblOptimizePercent" class="wod-dpsval">DATA</div>`

```
<?php     
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.askmrrobot.com/wow/optimize/eu/drak%27thul/Ecclesiastic');
$regexp = '^<div id=\"lblOptimizePercent\" class=\"wod-dpsval\">(.*)<\/div>^';
preg_match($regexp, $text, $matches);
$percentage = $matches[1];
echo $percentage;
```

This should give you DATA - the percentage value. But this doesn't happen! Why:

---

The data is dynamically inserted by a Javascript on client-side.
The id or class selector is used for DOM querying (element selection), then the data value is added.

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ - http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

jQuery example

On this site they deliver `<div id="lblOptimizePercent" class="wod-dpsval"></div>`to the client and then they use an update query like this: `$("#lblOptimizePercent").text("100%");` to update the percentage value.

If you want to query it on client-side, you might use `$("#lblOptimizePercent").text();`**

Try this in your console. It returns the percentage value.

---

How to scrape this page?

If you want to scrape this page with dynamic data, you need something like a Browser Environment for scraping: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/) are your friend.
Open the page with PhantomJS, launch the jQuery cmd from above and done.

This snippet should get you pretty close. You might save it as scrape.js then execute it with Phantom.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.askmrrobot.com/wow/optimize/eu/drak%27thul/Ecclesiastic', function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      alert(
         $("#lblOptimizePercent").text()
      );
    });
    phantom.exit()
  });
});
```

You can also save the "evaluated page" (now with data) and do the extract with PHP.
That's exactly like: Save Page in your browser and working on the saved HTML file.

Comment: Can this be done online? I mean, can I use jQuery on my page to get content from another page like this?

Comment: This would be a jQuery cross-domain Ajax Request, right?. It depends on the cross-origin policy in place. If they allow access, then it might work. Try it: `$.get('http://www.askmrrobot.com/wow/optimize/eu/drak%27thul/Ecclesiastic', function( data ) {
  alert( 'Successful cross-domain AJAX request.' );
});`

Comment: Console says: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.askmrrobot.com/wow/optimize/eu/drak%27thul/Ecclesiastic. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. So probably it is not possible.

Comment: Unlucky! Your remaining options: 1) find an API endpoint, which exposes JSON or XML, like http://swtor.askmrrobot.com/api/test/character/v1/0f95a940-4cf1-4af3-a922-666e312ff49c. But i doubt they provide this for the WOW optimizer. This would be to easy :) 2) use the PhantomJS/SlimerJS evaluated-page-scrape approach from above 3) a webproxy with page evaluation (js on) would work, too.

Comment: Regarding 1) the site uses JSON internally - http://www.askmrrobot.com/wod/json/getcharacterprofile/v4 . you can see that in your browsers network tab, look for GET requests containing "wod/json". These request work only if some headers are set correctly, mainly the request token from the page is needed. So, what might work too, is to scrape the page, then the token and then do a subsequent call with the token applied to get the json and to work directly with that.. this is hard to get right, but you get a lot of json data to work with.

Answer (score 2):

In Firebug or another webdeveloper tools you see the generated content, in Source code there is a blank element only.

First time, blank element is shown (during rendering site) and than using JS the content is filled.

Googlebot etc. can´t see this JS-generated content, but it´s no problem in this case.

Code:

```
document.getElementById('lblOptimizePercent').innerHTML = '94%';
```

Or similarly using jQuery:

```
$('#lblOptimizePercent').html('94%');
// need to load jQuery before, of course
```